# '@ionic/storage-angular', data get delete after refresh

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using angular in my ionic and I have followed everything based on this [docs](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage), so im using "@ionic/storage-angular", but my problem is when i refresh, data get deleted. Below is my code.

//app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

//storage.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
 })
export class StorageService {
    private _storage: Storage | null = null;
    constructor(private storage: Storage){
       this.init();
    }
    async init() {
        // https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage
        // If using, define drivers here: await this.storage.defineDriver(/*...*/);
        const storage = await this.storage.create();
        this._storage = storage;
     }
    public set(key: string, value: any) {
        this._storage?.set(key, value);
    }
    public get(key){
        return this._storage?.get(key);
    }
    public clear(){
        this._storage.clear();
    }
}
```

//this is how i used the service

```
await this.storageService.set('loginUser',{id: user.id,userName: user.first_name});
```

Comment: so what to do? @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: @top.eng Are you using cordova or Capacitor??

Comment: @top.eng have you found any solution on this ?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib That's not true. The `_ionicstorage` should also reset when we refresh the browser but its not.